# In T-SQL, why is the ISJSON function not filtering out bad data when used in a CTE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, json-query

I have a table with a `varchar(max)` column that stores JSON data and one of the records has an extra comma at the end of an array in the JSON. The following statement results in an error

> Unexpected character ',' is found...

Code:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonField, '$.SomeProperty') AS JsonData
FROM MyTable
```

But the following code works because of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonField, '$.SomeProperty') AS JsonData
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ISJSON(JsonField) = 1
```

I can use that statement as a CTE as follows:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonField, '$.SomeProperty') AS JsonData
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE ISJSON(JsonField) = 1
)
SELECT JsonData 
FROM cte
```

But when I try to filter on the cte, I get the same error:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonField, '$.SomeProperty') AS JsonData 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE ISJSON(JsonField) = 1
)
SELECT JsonData 
FROM cte 
WHERE LEN(JsonData) > 500
```

Obviously, I can move the 2nd WHERE clause up to the definition of the CTE, but there are other filters I want to use and this is the the most straight forward filter I can use to provide this example.

Am I missing something or is this a bug? My workaround is to use a temp table instead.

Comment: This is a frequent "feature" of table expressions, derived tables or views - the query optimizer does not necessarily build an excution plan that models the way your query is written, the order in which expressions are evaluated can be different. you could try using a *rowgoal* which might force the optimizer to evaluate the table expression first.

Comment: `… SELECT JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ISJSON(JsonField) = 1 THEN JsonField END, '$.SomeProperty') AS JsonData …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression so that the `JSON_QUERY` is only evaluated if the `ISJSON` condition is met.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISJSON(JsonField) = 1 THEN JSON_QUERY(JsonField, '$.SomeProperty') END AS JsonData
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ISJSON(JsonField) = 1
```

This is [mostly reliable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12941/3690). [The documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> You should only depend on order of evaluation of the WHEN conditions
> for scalar expressions (including non-correlated subqueries that
> return scalars), not for aggregate expressions.

And this is a scalar expression - not an aggregate. (One other case to be aware of is if you test this with a single literal value you can also encounter the error at plan compilation time as SQL Server tries to constant fold it but this shouldn't affect you as you are selecting from a table)

But really you need to be using SQL Server 2022 so you can test `ISJSON(JsonField, OBJECT)`.

Otherwise the string `'1'` will pass the `ISJSON` check (as `ISJSON(JsonField, VALUE)` is `1`) but still barf at the `JSON_QUERY`.

I suppose on earlier versions you could also add an additional condition (to both `CASE` and `WHERE`) that `JsonField` is `LIKE '{%'`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. You'll see the same kind of thing with people trying to use `IsNumeric()` or `IsDate()` to pre-filter a field for number or date values, and the answer is the same: a database server may decide it's more efficient to run the function call *BEFORE* the where clause, and there's really nothing you can do about it except design the schema and validation to *not have mixed or broken data in the first place*.

So you can use a function to select only the records where `IsJSON()` is `1`, but if you actually try to parse into the JSON data all bets are off. It's more useful to select records where `IsJSON()` is `0`, without parsing the JSON on the DB server, so you can fix them in client code.

There's also [`Try_Cast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) now, but I don't recall whether it supports JSON.